# How can I tell a control to NOT redraw itself?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried something like:

```
horizontalPictureScroller1.SuspendLayout();
horizontalPictureScroller1.DeleteSelectedImages();
horizontalPictureScroller1.ResumeLayout();
```

But it's still lagging visually when I run the DeleteSelectedImages() method.

Is there some way to manually tell a control to NOT redraw itself until I tell it to start drawing itself again?

Using Windows Forms and .NET 4

Comment: What do you mean it's lagging visually?  What are you doing after ResumeLayout()?

Comment: Have you tried turning on doublebuffering to remove the flickering?

Comment: Can you override OnRender while you're doing your stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is that your screen updates during the delete operation resulting in flickering.

The SuspendLayout and ResumeLayour methods [only suspend the layout of the control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b8633a9f-2c55-41ca-8872-0e28b1400e86). It does not stop the control from redrawing or resizing.

You should enable [DoubleBuffering](http://geekswithblogs.net/phinoppix/articles/81838.aspx) on the control.

You should create a new control class derived from the WinForms control you are using here. In the constructor of this class enable the double buffering using `SetStyle` method.

Assuming that your control `horizontalPictureScroller1` is a PictureBox -

```
class MyControl : System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
                ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
                true);
        }
    }
```